# Sum values ​from a treeview column

Tags: python, mysql, tkinter, treeview

Good,

I'm trying to sum the values ​​of a column, while inputting it. Since I put a code in the entry and check if it exists and put it in columns in treeview, and I would like to add only the "price" values, but I can't do it, I get the data from the price column, but I can't get if This 5.99 I have entered another 5.99 add up and give me a total, as I add a price.

What I can be doing wrong? or what I have wrong

Any additional information would be appreciated.

```
def Cesta(self):
    self.conex()

    self.b_codigo = self.s_Codigo.get()

    self.sql3 = "SELECT * FROM productos WHERE codigo = %s"
    self.mycursor.execute(self.sql3,[(self.b_codigo)])
    self.r_codigo = self.mycursor.fetchall()

    self.row3 = [item['nombre'] for item in self.r_codigo]

    if self.s_Codigo.get() == "":
        MessageBox.showinfo("ERROR", "DEBES INTRODUCIR DATOS", icon="error")
    elif self.r_codigo:
        for self.x2 in self.r_codigo:
            print (self.x2["nombre"], self.x2["talla"], self.x2["precio"]+"€")
            self.tree.insert('', 'end', text=self.x2["nombre"], values=(self.x2["talla"],self.x2["precio"]+" €"))

        print(self.x2["fecha"])
        for self.item in self.tree.get_children():
            self.resultado = 0
            self.celda = int(self.tree.set(self.item,"col2"))
            self.total = int(self.resultado) + int(float(self.celda))
            print(self.total)
    else:
        MessageBox.showinfo("ERROR", "EL CODIGO INTRODUCIDO NO ES CORRECTO", icon="error")

    self.clear_entry()
```

`

```
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1921, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "/Users/tomas/Downloads/PROYECTO/main.py", line 205, in Cesta
    self.celda = int(self.tree.set(self.item,"col2"))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '134,99 €'
[Finished in 6.7s]
```

`

```
self.tree = ttk.Treeview(self.pagina1,columns=("col1","col2"), height=50)
    self.tree.grid(column=0, row=2, padx=50, pady=100)

    ### COLUMNAS ###
    self.tree.column("#0",width=250)
    self.tree.column("col1",width=150, anchor=CENTER)
    self.tree.column("col2",width=150, anchor=CENTER)

    ### NOMBRES COLUMNAS ###
    self.tree.heading("#0", text="Articulo", anchor=CENTER)
    self.tree.heading("col1", text="Talla", anchor=CENTER)
    self.tree.heading("col2", text="Precio", anchor=CENTER)
```

Everything else is going well for me, but the part in which I want to add the results of the price column does not

What am I doing wrong, to be able to add the values ​​of the prices column every time I insert a new product?

Comment: The error tells you obviously that "134,99 €" is not a valid integer.

Comment: Hi, I've already tried that, so it only shows me the value of the entered item, but it doesn't add it to the previous one.

Comment: The string is not a valid integer, so how can you convert it and sum it? Also you have reset `self.resultado` to 0 in each iteration of the for loop, so even the string is a value integer, `self.resultado` will be the last value finally.

Comment: Hello, I have already managed to solve the error, the new price is already added to the old one, thanks for making me reflect on it.

Answer (score 0):

I have already managed to solve the error, the new price is already added to the old one, thanks for making me reflect on it.

```
for self.x2 in self.r_codigo:
            print (self.x2["nombre"], self.x2["talla"], self.x2["precio"]+"€")
            self.tree.insert('', 'end', text=self.x2["nombre"], values=(self.x2["talla"],self.x2["precio"]))

        self.total = 0
        
        for self.item in self.tree.get_children():  
            self.celda = float(self.tree.set(self.item,"col2"))
            self.total+=self.celda
            print(self.total)
```